# SVG img shows space above and below

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

I can't understand why in this site http://beta.architetturaecosostenibile.it/ with some old browsers like Safari 5 ore also the stock browser of Android 4.1 or Internet Explorer 8, I get white space above and below the top SVG image (the logo).

Can anyone help me understand which is the issue?

Comment: can you show us the logo??? or code here

Comment: You che open the link in my problem description, here above. In the top of the page the first image you will see is the logo. This did you mean?

Comment: **i am assuming it is not the svg logo giving space.**

    body>header {
    padding: 2.33333rem 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    }

here you need to work around how much space you needed

Comment: Open the page with Chrome, this is the normal padding. After, open the page with Safari 5 or above named browsers, this is the "space" i mean: http://imgur.com/Sn6DhKq